# Maximize a sum of posynomials

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am dealing with an optimization problem where I have to maximize a sum of posynomials subject to affine constraints. The formulation of the problem (**P**) is as follows:

$$\text{maximize } f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \sum_{j=1}^m c_j \prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{a_{i,j}}\\
\text{subject to } h(\boldsymbol{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n b_ix_i + C = 0 \text{ and } x_i \le 1, i \in \{1,...,n\}\\
\text{where } \boldsymbol{x} = (x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R}_{++}^n \text{ is the variable;}\\
\text{and } (c_1,...c_m) \in \mathbb{R}_{++}^m\\
\text{and } (b_1,...,b_n) \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^n\\
\text{and } a_{ij} \in \mathbb{N}, \forall (i,j) \in [1..n]^2$$

Since the coefficients $c_i$ are strictly positive, this would conveniently be a geometric program (**GP**) *if* it was about minimizing $f(\boldsymbol{x})$, since $f$ can be made convex after a logarithmic change of variable.

Note that maximizing $f$ is equivalent to minimizing $$-f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \sum_{j=1}^m -c_j \prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{a_{i,j}}$$ where $-c_j < 0$ - that is, $-f$ is a signomial and (**P**) becomes a signomial optimization problem (**SP**), which is much harder to solve than a (**GP**).

Even though there is no known convexification of general (**SP**) problems, I was wondering if, in the specific scope of (**P**), and especially the fact that $f$ is directly the opposite of a posynomial, a methodology existed to avoid having to solve an (**SP**) problem?

Note that if $m=1$, then $f$ becomes a monomial and therefore we have a (**GP**) problem with the minimization of $1/f$, which is also a monomial.

Comment: How large is the problem?

Comment: In terms of order of magnitudes, I would say $1 < n \leqslant 10$, $10 \leqslant m \leqslant 100$, $c_j$ can be normalized and belong to $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$, $0 \leqslant a_{ij} \leqslant 10$. Smaller values of $m$ ($\leqslant 10$) will be chosen if the problem is computationally too expensive.

Comment: Just do the regular transformation to a GP. By the maximum principle, the maximum of a convex function over a bounded convex set is attained at an extreme point of the feasible set. Perhaps you could add a sufficiently large bounding box to the feasible region to make it bounded.

Comment: The problem you presented generalizes polynomial optimization over your feasible set, and thus I do not believe any efficient algorithm is possible.